# how to use getRoles method of Weblogic role mapping provider?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, weblogic, jaas

Could somebody please provide the usage of the `getRoles()` method of a Weblogic role mapping provider? How is this used in code?

Comment: do you mean how the security-role-assignment works in weblogic.xml?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy No..I want to get user roles from the AD auth provider..How can i do that? I am using j_security_check for authentication..How can i get roles for the perticuler user..so that I can set his/her menu for the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this

```
        if ((request.getUserPrincipal().getName()) != null) {
            String userName = request.getUserPrincipal().getName().trim();
            session.setAttribute("userName", userName);
            .....
            if (request.isUserInRole("ADMINS")) {
              //do actions here
            }
        }
```